# Multivariate Inequalities: When To Switch The Sign?

Tags: inequality

I need to solve the following inequality ($c \neq 1$):

$$c^n < \frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c}$$

Plugging in simple numbers like $c=2$, $n=2$ results in $4 < 7$, so it appears that this inequality is true.

However upon just one simple algebraic step we get:

$$(1-c)c^n<1-c^{n+1}$$

Which, once again plugging in $c=2, n=2$ we now have $-4 < -7$ which is no longer true. Thus, clearly the sign *needed to be flipped* during this step. But this raises an interesting phenomenon: we do not know if $(1-c)$ is going to be positive or negative before this step and, thus, do not know if the sign needs to be flipped.

Therefore, generally speaking, when solving a multivariate inequality like seen above, must we split the answer into two cases, one for $c>1$ and one for $c<1$?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct? I think that $c \in \left(0,1\right)$.

Comment: Rather than saying "simple algebraic step" you should say "multiply both sides by $1-c$" ... then you need to know that multiplying by a positive number keeps the sense of the inequality, while multiplying by a negative number reverses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must do case work:
if $$1-c>0$$ then $$c<1$$ and we have $$c^n-c^{n+1}<1-c^{n+1}$$ therefore $$c^n<1$$
if $$1<c$$ then we get
$$(1-c)c^n>1-c^{n+1}$$ therefore $$c^n>1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is said that we do not know if $1-c$ is positive or negative until later. But that doesn't stop us from doing the following:
\begin{align}
& c^n < \frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c} \\[10pt]
& 0 < c^n - \frac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c} \\[10pt]
& 0 < \frac{c^n(1-c)-(1-c^{n+1})}{1-c} \\[10pt]
& 0 < \frac{c^n - c^{n+1} - 1 + c^{n+1}}{1-c} \\[10pt]
& 0 < \frac{c^n-1}{1-c}
\end{align}
Then we can ask on which intervals $1-c$ is positive and negative, and on which intervals $c^n-1$ is positive and negative. The fraction is positive if the numerator and denominator are either both positive or both negative.